# connecting to mysql in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, connector-net

Im trying to connect MySql from VB.NET in visual basic 2010. I wanted to query the db just to get one return is response to my proID once I click the button. it successfully show connection has been establish but I can't seems to run any sql query on it. what might have been wrong?

This is the error I got from immediate window:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
```

Lets assume num is 1001 from the keypress event.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private connStr As String = "server=localhost;" & _
                "user id=root;Password=1234561;" & _
                "database = test"
    Dim num As Integer


Private Sub TextBox1_keypress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Dim str As String
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
        str = TextBox1.Text
        Dim splitVals As String() = str.Split(" ")
        num = splitVals(1)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM products"
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query)
    Try
        con.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Database Connected")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Connection.Close()

        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ExecuteNonQuery** is used for SQL statements that don't return any data (For example, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).

What do you want to achieve? If you want to fetch all records from `product` table and display it on a `datagrid`, then try this:

```
Using xConn as New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Using xComm as new MySQLCommand()
        xComm.Connection = xConn
        xComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM products"
        Using xAdapter as new MySQLDAtaAdapter(xComm)
            Dim ds as new Dataset
            xConn.Open()
            xAdapter.Fill(ds)
            datagridview1.datasource = ds.tables(0)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
Dim xPrice as Integer = 0
Using xConn as New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Using xComm as new MySQLCommand()
        xComm.Connection = xConn
        xComm.CommandText = "SELECT ProductPrice FROM products WHERE proID = @xID"
            xComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("xID", "Value Here")
            xConn.Open()
            xPrice = CInt(xComm.ExecuteScalar())
            xConn.Close
    End Using
End Using

Msgbox xPrice
```

Comment: i only wanted to get 1 field from db.
i got the proID, and i wanted to fetch the price. is it possible of just fetching 1 field?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM products"
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim da as New MySqlDataAdapter() 
    Dim ds as New DataSet
    Try
        con.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Database Connected")
        da=New MySqlDataAdapter(query,con)
        da.fill(ds,"products") 
        DataGridView1.DataSource=ds.Tables("products")
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```